# How do I assign a view to a panel node in drupal

Tags: views, entities, nodes, panels, display-suite

I have a panel that shows a teaser of a bunch of nodes of a certain content type. I am attempting to replicate this for a new content type.

I have created a similar content type with the exact same fields. I have cloned the view(**type = content pane**) and changed the filter to the correct content type. I have now created a page of content type panel.

**Question:** How do I assign the view to that page(node)? Does it have something to do with display suite and the layout?

I am using Drupal 6.

**EDIT:** To put the above in another way:

I have a panel and I don't know how to apply a view to it. So I have my view that basically aggregates a bunch of nodes based on content type. I'm not sure how to add panel content to the panel. But the panel content being the query the view execute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are display the panel on a node then you need to add a variant of the **node/%node** page. In Drupal 7 you would

1. Edit the **node_view** (node/%node) page.
2. Press *Clone* to create a variant of your current page.
3. Under *Selection rules* add *Node:type* and select your new content type.
4. Ensure that the new variant is above your current variant, or add Selection rules to your current variant too.
5. In your new variant under *Content* replace the old View with the new View.

Note: If the only change to the View (and Page) is the Content type then you could have used the Content type of the node being viewed as a Contextual filter on the View. Then there would be no need for a Panel variant or another View.

Comment: I went to the /node/%node page and had a look at the existing variant. (Only one) It didn't look like it was the one for the content type I wanted to clone. What could this mean? (I'm somewhat new to drupal)

Could it have anything to do with "Display suite layouts" or "build modes"?

Comment: I disabled the variant and it didn't break any of the pages if that helps.

Comment: So you need to figure out which is the panel you are currently using and clone that. You can guess by comparing the path for the page you like and the paths of the enabled pages in Page Manager. Display Suite I can't help with. Is it possible you aren't using a panel page? Can you give an example path? Is it node/123 for example?